# Fitting t-distribution in R: scaling parameter

Tags: r, distributions, maximum-likelihood, fitting, robust

How do I fit the parameters of a t-distribution, i.e. the parameters corresponding to the 'mean' and 'standard deviation' of a normal distribution. I assume they are called 'mean' and 'scaling/degrees of freedom' for a t-distribution?

The following code often results in 'optimization failed' errors.

```
library(MASS)
fitdistr(x, "t")
```

Do I have to scale x first or convert into probabilities? How best to do that?

Comment: It fails not because you have to scale parameters, but because optimizer fails. See my answer below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`fitdistr` uses maximum-likelihood and optimization techniques to find parameters of a given distribution. Sometimes, especially for t-distribution, as @user12719 noticed, the optimization in the form:

```
fitdistr(x, "t")
```

fails with an error.

In this case you should give optimizer a hand by providing starting point and lower bound to start searching for optimal parameters:

```
fitdistr(x, "t", start = list(m=mean(x),s=sd(x), df=3), lower=c(-1, 0.001,1))
```

Note, `df=3` is your best guess at what an "optimal" `df` could be. After providing this additional info your error will be gone.

Couple of excerpts to help you better understand the inner mechanics of `fitdistr`:

> For the Normal, log-Normal, geometric, exponential and Poisson distributions the closed-form MLEs (and exact standard errors) are used, and `start` should not be supplied.

...

> For the following named distributions, reasonable starting values will be computed if `start` is omitted or only partially specified: "cauchy", "gamma", "logistic", "negative binomial" (parametrized by mu and size), "t" and "weibull". Note that these starting values may not be good enough if the fit is poor: in particular they are not resistant to outliers unless the fitted distribution is long-tailed.

Comment: Both answers (Flom and Bushmanov) are helpful. I'm picking this one, because it makes it more explicit that with the right initial values and constraints 'fitdistr' optimization converges.

Answer (score 14):

MASS, the book (4th edition, page 110) advises against trying to estimate $\nu$, the degrees of freedom parameter in the $t$-distribution with maximum likelihood (with some literature references: [Lange et al. (1989), "Robust statistical modeling Using the t distribution", *JASA*, **84**, 408](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1989.10478852), and
[Fernandez & Steel (1999), "Multivariate Student-*t* regression models: Pitfalls and inference", *Biometrika*, **86**, 1](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/86/1/153.abstract)).

The reason is that the likelihood function for $\nu$ based on the t density function, may be unbounded and will in those cases not give a well defined maximum. Let us look at an artificial example where location and scale is known (as the standard $t$-distribution) and only the degrees of freedom is unknown. Below is some R code, simulating some data, defining the log-likelihood function and plotting it:

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 10
x <- rt(n,  df=2.5)

make_loglik  <-  function(x)
    Vectorize( function(nu) sum(dt(x, df=nu,  log=TRUE)) )

loglik  <-  make_loglik(x)
plot(loglik,  from=1,  to=100,  main="loglikelihood function for df     parameter", xlab="degrees of freedom")
abline(v=2.5,  col="red2")
```

[image]

If you play around with this code, you can find some cases where there is a well-defined maximum, especially when the sample size $n$ is large.  But is the maximum likelihood estimator then any good?

Let us try some simulations:

```
t_nu_mle  <-  function(x) {
    loglik  <-  make_loglik(x)
    res  <-  optimize(loglik, interval=c(0.01, 200), maximum=TRUE)$maximum
    res   
}

nus  <-  replicate(1000, {x <- rt(10, df=2.5)
    t_nu_mle(x) }, simplify=TRUE)

> mean(nus)
[1] 45.20767
> sd(nus)
[1] 78.77813
```

Showing the estimation is very unstable (looking at the histogram, a sizable portion of the estimated values is at the upper limit given to optimize of 200).

Repeating with a larger sample size:

```
nus  <-  replicate(1000, {x <- rt(50, df=2.5)
    t_nu_mle(x) }, simplify=TRUE)
> mean(nus)
[1] 4.342724
> sd(nus)
[1] 14.40137
```

which is much better, but the mean is still way above the true value of 2.5.

Then remember that this is a simplified version of the real problem where location and scale parameters also have to be estimated.

If the reason of using the $t$-distribution is to "robustify", then estimating $\nu$ from the data may well destroy the robustness.

Comment: Your conclusion that the problems of estimating df might actually work against the reason to choose a t-distribution in the first place (i.e. robustness) is thought provoking.

Comment: (+1) "Unbounded above" isn't a wrong answer & might well be useful for some purposes when coupled with an interval estimate. The important thing is not to blindly use the observed Fisher information to form Wald confidence intervals.

Answer (score 10):

In the help for fitdistr is this example:

```
fitdistr(x2, "t", df = 9)
```

indicating that you just need a value for df. But that assumes standardization.

For more control, they also show

```
mydt <- function(x, m, s, df) dt((x-m)/s, df)/s
fitdistr(x2, mydt, list(m = 0, s = 1), df = 9, lower = c(-Inf, 0))
```

where the parameters would be m = mean, s = standard deviation, df = degrees of freedom

Comment: I guess I am confused about the parameters of a t-distribution. Does it have 2 (mean,df) or 3 (mean, standard deviation, df) parameters? I was wondering if one could fit the parameter 'df'.

Comment: @user12719 The [Student's-t distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) has three parameters: location, scale and degrees of freedom. They are not referred as mean, standard deviation and df because the mean and the variance of this distribution depend on the three parameters. Also, they do not exists in some cases. Peter Flom is fixing the df but this can be considered as an unknown parameter as well.

Comment: @Procrastinator I was just going from the help files - m and s are shown, which clearly stand for mean and sd, right? Is this an error in the help files for MASS? (If so, who will tell them?????).  Of course df can vary too.

Comment: @PeterFlom In the case of the [Cauchy distribution](http://127.0.0.1:25031/library/stats/html/Cauchy.html) it is explicit that m and s are the location and scale. I agree the notation m and s suggests that they represent the mean and standard deviation, respectively. But this may just be a simplification of `\mu` and `\sigma` as well. +1 long ago, by the way.

Comment: @PeterFlom Does this citation from the R's help file imply that df is **always** 9 for students distribution? Don't you think df should be estimated as well? Actually, the absence of `df` is the cause for the error, and the right answer should provide some recipe to finding it.

Comment: @PeterFlom BTW, if you read the help file couple of lines above your citation, you'll find why `df=9` is good in their example and irrelevant here.

Comment: MASS (the book, 4th edition, page 110) advices against trying to fit $\nu$,thedegrees of freedom parameters (with references to literature). The problem is that the likelihood function is **unbounded** as a function of $\nu$, which leads to the mle lacking its usually good properties!

Comment: @PeterFlom how would simulate a density with these scale and location parameters using R's rt function? All I see there is the non-centrality parameter ncp and it's not clear how to get from one formulation to the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fitdistrplus library after extending the location and scaling parameters for the student t in base R according to this article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family). Below is sample code

```
library(fitdistrplus)
x<-rt(100,23)
dt_ls <- function(x, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1) 1/sigma * dt((x - mu)/sigma, df)
pt_ls <- function(q, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1)  pt((q - mu)/sigma, df)
qt_ls <- function(p, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1)  qt(p, df)*sigma + mu
rt_ls <- function(n, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1)  rt(n,df)*sigma + mu
fit.t<-fitdist(x, 't_ls', start =list(df=1,mu=mean(x),sigma=sd(x))) 
summary(fit.t)
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameters of the t-distribution are referred to as the location, scale, and degrees of freedom $\nu$.  The location can be estimated by the mean of the samples if $\nu > 1$; otherwise the mean is not defined. By not defined, this means that increasing the sample size will not converge to a particular value.  The scale is a generalization of the standard-deviation.  The scale $\sigma$ can be estimated from the standard-deviation of the samples if $\nu > 2$. $\sigma_{est} = E[(X-\mu)^2]^{1/2} sqrt[(\nu - 2)/\nu]$.

In addition to the established methods, new closed-formed estimates that achieve the maximum likelihood have been defined in two papers. In my paper ["Use of the geometric mean as a statistic for the scale of the coupled Gaussian distribution"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437118311816) The Coupled Gaussian is equivalent to the Student's t but is expressed in terms of the shape or coupling, which is inverse to $\nu$. I showed a functional relationship between the scale, DoF and the geometric mean. Thus the function can be used to estimate either scale or DoF if the other is known.

In my paper ["Independent Approximates enable closed-form estimation of heavy-tailed distributions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.11026) I showed that linear closed-form functions exist for estimating the location and scale parameters of the Student's t distribution. These functions are formed by selecting subsamples referred to as Independent Approximates (IAs). The IAs are formed by pairs, triplets, or n-tuples that are approximately equal.  The IA-pairs are guaranteed to have a mean and can be used to estimate the location. The IA-triplets are guaranteed to have a finite second-moment and can be used to estimate the scale.

There is Mathematica code referenced in the IA paper.  Perhaps someone would be interested in implementing the method in R.

Answer (score 1):

@SergeyBushmanov points out that sometimes you need to give maximum likelihood estimation a hand by providing appropriate starting point and lower/upper bounds for the optimization algorithm to find the MLE.

Another way to give the likelihood a hand is to augment it with a (weakly) informative prior and do Bayesian estimation. This approach is most applicable if we have domain information to help us formulate a useful prior.

I'll illustrate one Bayesian solution to the $t$ distribution fitting problem in the setting where @kjetilbhalvorsen demonstrates that the MLE approach fails: sample size $n = 10$, location $\mu = 0$, scale $\sigma = 1$ and degrees of freedom $\nu = 2.5$. I'll use the [brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html) package to do the Bayesian model fitting and two different priors for the degrees of freedom $\nu$:

- strongly informative prior: $\nu \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(1, 0.3)$ and
- informative prior: $\nu \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(1, 0.1)$,

with the constraint $\nu > 1$ (otherwise the mean of the $t$ distribution is undefined.)

Both choices indicate there is high prior probability the degrees of freedom are less than 5: under the informative prior, $\operatorname{Pr}(\nu<5) = 0.33$ and under the strongly informative prior, $\operatorname{Pr}(\nu<5) = 0.7$. So both priors are quite "opinionated", which we would like to avoid in general. [The default `brms` prior on the degrees of freedom is $\operatorname{Gamma}(2, 0.1)$.] On the other hand, in general we would also probably collect more than $n = 10$ observations for a study where we know there is a lot of variability in the outcome.

[image]

And here is how to do Bayesian $t$ distribution fitting with [brms::brm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/brms/versions/2.19.0/topics/brm).

First we simulate a sample of size $n$ from $t(\mu=0,\sigma=1,\nu=2.5)$ where $\mu$ is the location, $\sigma$ is the scale and $\nu$ are the degrees of freedom.

```r
n <- 10
mu <- 0
sigma <- 1
nu <- 2.5
x <- rt(n, nu) * sigma + mu
```

Then we fit an intercept-only $t$-family model.

```r
fit.brm <- brm(
  x ~ 1,
  family = student,
  data = data.frame(x),
  prior = c(
    prior(student_t(3, 0, 2.5), class = "Intercept"),
    prior(student_t(3, 0, 2.5), class = "sigma"),
    prior(gamma(1, 0.3), class = "nu")
  )
)
```

While the posterior distributions of the location $\mu$ and scale $\sigma$ are reasonably symmetric, the posterior of the degrees of freedom $\nu$ is very skewed. So I will use the posterior mode (rather than the posterior mean or the posterior median) to estimate the parameters.

[image]

```r
round(
  apply(posterior, 2, mode), 3
)
#>     μ     σ     ν 
#> 0.161 0.785 2.164
```

And finally, I repeat the three analyses (MLE, Bayesian with weakly informative prior, Bayesian with informative prior) 200 times. Each analysis estimates all three parameters (location $\mu$, scale $\sigma$ and degrees of freedom $\nu$) but below I plot histograms of the estimated degrees of freedom only. The true $\nu$ is 2.5.

Maximum likelihood estimation fails dramatically more than half of the time (100 is the upper bound for $\nu$ in the optimization). Bayesian estimation doesn't fail in any of the 200 simulations but the estimate is biased upwards unless the prior information indicates strongly that we expect *a priori* only a few degrees of freedom.

[image]