# Robust GAM that covers Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, robust, generalized-additive-model

I was looking at CrossValidate archives as well as r-archives and crantastic...for a package that has a robust approach to generalized additive models. I found two packages "robustgam" and "rgam" but their implemented functions 
cover only binomial and Poisson distributions (pls correct me if I am wrong).

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could share with us other R-packages or robust approaches of general additive modeling that might have a better performance with  small data sets ($n<100$ records or 50 -100 records).

Comment: Interesting thought...I am not sure but sounds that it might work! Did you have in mind a specific pacgage like mgcv, or robustgam or rgam? Thank you VERY MUCH for your immediate response. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: no, that was wrong...

Comment: yes...thank you any new ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The *mgcv* package contains a scaled-t family for the conditional distribution of the response, that, like the Gaussian, has support for the entire real line (is suitable for a response that is continuous and is bounded at -Inf and +Inf), but which has heavier tails than the Gaussian.

Estimating the model requires estimating another parameter of the distribution, the degrees of freedom, the smaller the degrees of freedom the heavier the tails of the conditional distribution of the response.

Because of the heavier tails in this distribution, the model is made more robust to more extreme observations as they have higher probability density until the scaled-t with suitable degrees of freedom than under the Gaussian, all else equal. As a result, the model doesn't need to move the fitted smoother towards these extreme values, to achieve a reasonable fit.

To use it, use `family = scat()` in the call the `gam()` or `bam()`.

Comment: This was what I was thinking. Question, though: does this use the same error distribution for every input (akin to OLS having constant variance), or are the degrees of freedom allowed to change?

Comment: @Dave The `scat` family in *mgcv* doesn't allow for a linear predictor (beyond an intercept) for $\nu$; in general though, one could have a model for $\nu$. The *VGAM*, *gamlss* packages allow for this as do more general packages like *brms*/*Stan* etc

Comment: But see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45784/fitting-t-distribution-in-r-scaling-parameter/195113#195113, MASS (the book) advices against trying to estimate $\nu$, it looses robustness.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yep; good point. The *gamlss* package at least parameterises the its *t* distribution using *mu*, *sigma* and *nu*. Not sure how this changes things with respect to your Answer & the stuff in MASS?