# fitdistr among Cauchy / Student-T / Normal distributions in R

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, likelihood-ratio, t-distribution, cauchy-distribution

I am posting this, hoping that it will also be useful to others.  see also [Fitting t-distribution in R: scaling parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45784/fitting-t-distribution-in-r-scaling-parameter) .

my data series x is fat-tailed, 1063 obs.  it seems straightforward to determine whether I can reject a cauchy:

```
> library(fitdistrplus)
> ca <- fitdistr(x, "cauchy")

> summary(ca)
Fitting of the distribution ' cauchy ' by maximum likelihood
Parameters :
         estimate Std. Error
location  0.01140   0.001277
scale     0.02612   0.001031
Loglikelihood:  1588   AIC:  -3172   BIC:  -3162

Goodness-of-fit statistics
                             1-mle-cauchy
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic      0.07703
Cramer-von Mises statistic        1.21856
Anderson-Darling statistic       12.35285

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                               1-mle-cauchy
Aikake's Information Criterion        -3172
```

I would like to know whether the data can reject the null hypothesis that x was drawn from the cauchy.  It would be nice if fitdist gave an interpretation of the statistics itself, but I think I can explain it.  I just need to compare, e.g., my K-S of 0.077 to the K-S critical value of 1.63/sqrt(length(x))=0.05.  we can reject the null that the data is from a cauchy.

now, the cauchy and normal are both special cases of the Student-T.  I would like to see where in the family of student-t distributions x would be, and how well freeing this parameter helps compared with the cauchy.  alas, fitdistr first needs a df provided as a parameter.  I can match the kurtosis of x to determine the best match.  a student-T has a kurtosis of 6/(df-4), so for my x with kurtosis of 10.7, my df should be about 4.5.  and now,

```
 t4 <- fitdistr(x, "t", df=4.5)
```

which for me gives a t4$loklik of about 1699.

the coup de grace should be to test how good this freed-up df performs vs. the restricted cauchy with something like

```
 library(lmtest)
 lrtest( ca, t4 )
```

i.e., something like 2*log-LR compared to the Chi-sq.  with a difference of 111, and we are way above the 10.8 critical level at 0.1% for a dimensionality difference of 1.  is this built into R fitdistr somehow, but I just overlooked it?  right approach?

Comment: when you refer to your data as a 'series' ... are your values observed over time?

Comment: indeed in my application.  and the iid assumption is heroic.  but, this question is not just my specific application.  it is generic.

Comment: can you share (a subsample) of the data here?

Comment: http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html

Comment: @ivoWelch thanks a lot for the link, but which of the many files is your particular dataset?

Comment: Fama-French, 3 factors, daily at http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily_CSV.zip is a great starter for daily returns on some big portfolios.

Comment: @ivoWelch thanks for the pointer. in your OP you have 1063 observations; the dataset you pointed to has 23,000 observations.  Any particular subset I should use? Or is your question general, not specific to your particular 1063 observations dataset?  And also: are you really interested in fitting/testing a Cauchy specifically, or more generally test for existence of first k moments / estimating tail parameters?

Comment: there are daily and monthly data.  I probably used monthly.  you probably used daily.  it was general.

Comment: @ivoWelch can you edit the original post to clarify whats your exact question you want to know.  I am not sure if you ask about fitting t distributions in general, testing "H0: X ~ Cauchy", a nice interface for likelihood ratio tests in R, ...